# Full sphere (or double hemi sphere) lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I have an object in the world centre, that I want fully lit from a sphere.

In Blender, you can add hemi-sphere lights. I did not find a way to change the hemisphere into a full sphere. Can that be done?

As an alternative, I thought I would just add two hemispherical lights to my scene, like so:

[image]

To my surprise, this does **not** yield an object, evenly lit from all sides.

The hexagons on this torus that are perfectly vertical, receive **zero** light.

[image]

Why wouldn't two hemispherical lights add up to a scene that is fully lit from all sides? And second, how should I achieve this instead? I am using Cycles.

Comment: Do you mean homogeneous from all sides?

Comment: Blender internal or cycles?

Comment: @cegaton Added the cycles tag (deducted from the last render).

Comment: Why don't you use an emissive sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cycles has no support for hemi lights.

But you can do this with no lights at all, the same way you would do it if you were lighting using an HDR image.

Just make the world white and your object will be lit from a sphere that surrounds the scene.

It will give you flat even lighting from all directions.

[image]

Comment: Does it still cast shadows?

Comment: @Bram Yes, why don't you just try it. It only takes a minute.